# Sending image file as binary to mssql database through rest webservice with android

Tags: android, sql, image, web-services, rest

I have this image file `.png` that was taken by my android's camera which I saved to the phone. So I want to send this PNG as a binary to my SQL database.

Here's what I do:

I save the picture and then run this code to post below:

```
 public static void uploadImage(final String url, final File file) {
    final HttpClient myHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Image attaching
                MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                multipartEntity.addBinaryBody("photo", file, ContentType.create("image/png"), file.getName());
                //Json string attaching
                HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
                put.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
                HttpResponse response = myHttpClient.execute(put);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

But on the rest web service side I couldn't exactly figure out how to receive this binary and then send it to the database as a binary also.
I'd appreciate the help a lot, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution turned out to be actually not so hard. I just kept on trying, You convert it to string, the whole image send it like that to the web service and from the web service you just insert it into the sql database, I did it by creating a `binary` column in my table, which worked pretty well.